# Different results in numpy vs matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to implement a gradient descent algorithm that was previously written in matlab in python with numpy, but I'm getting a set of similar but different results.

Here's the matlab code

```
function [theta] = gradientDescentMulti(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

m = length(y);
num_features = size(X,2);
for iter = 1:num_iters;
    temp_theta = theta;
    for i = 1:num_features
        temp_theta(i) = theta(i)-((alpha/m)*(X * theta - y)'*X(:,i));
    end
    theta = temp_theta;
end


end
```

and my python version

```
def gradient_descent(X,y, alpha, trials):

    m = X.shape[0]
    n = X.shape[1]
    theta = np.zeros((n, 1))

    for i in range(trials):

        temp_theta = theta
        for p in range(n):
            thetaX = np.dot(X, theta)
            tMinY = thetaX-y
            temp_theta[p] = temp_theta[p]-(alpha/m)*np.dot(tMinY.T, X[:,p:p+1])

        theta = temp_theta

    return theta
```

Test case and results in matlab

```
X = [1 2 1 3; 1 7 1 9; 1 1 8 1; 1 3 7 4]
y = [2 ; 5 ; 5 ; 6];
[theta] = gradientDescentMulti(X, y, zeros(4,1), 0.01, 1);

theta =

    0.0450
    0.1550
    0.2225
    0.2000
```

test case and result in python

```
test_X = np.array([[1,2,1,3],[1,7,1,9],[1,1,8,1],[1,3,7,4]])
test_y = np.array([[2], [5], [5], [6]])
theta, cost = gradient_descent(test_X, test_y, 0.01, 1)
print theta
>>[[ 0.045     ]
  [ 0.1535375 ]
  [ 0.20600144]
  [ 0.14189214]]
```

Comment: @Kartik "MATLAB results might be wrong" is really not a helpful suggestion, without a detailed reason.

Comment: My comment was misunderstood. I was sharing my experience with you, and I was suggesting that you could use another software to resolve this, if you can. (I am aware that you may not have access to another software.) Explaining why MATLAB results were wrong when I tried a simple histogram is something I didn't have the ken to research or figure out at that time. I blamed it on the closed source nature of MATLAB, and presumed something slipped through their tests, and continued on with Python, which I felt much more "at home" using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line in your Python:

```
    temp_theta = theta
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  It doesn't make a copy of `theta` and "assign" it to the "variable" `temp_theta` -- it just says "`temp_theta` is now a new name for the object currently named by `theta`".

So when you modify `temp_theta` here:

```
        temp_theta[p] = temp_theta[p]-(alpha/m)*np.dot(tMinY.T, X[:,p:p+1])
```

You're actually modifying `theta` -- because there's only the one array, now with two names.

If you instead write

```
    temp_theta = theta.copy()
```

you'll get something like

```
(3.5) dsm@notebook:~/coding$ python peter.py
[[ 0.045 ]
 [ 0.155 ]
 [ 0.2225]
 [ 0.2   ]]
```

which matches your Matlab results.